# Replace html placeholder text with html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I have a scenario where i have in my page a placeholder text that I will replace after the page is fully loaded.
My problem is that the text i need to replace is a plugin of the recaptcha image, for example:

I have the text `loading...` which will be replaced by:

```
<recaptcha:recaptchacontrol ID='recaptcha' runat='server' PublicKey='kfldsjfh4378qyf43h4eidfhew' PrivateKey='sdflkdsfy908s6dfdsfkj' Theme='clean' />
```

I couldn't find a way to do so, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: by the way, why do you tell everyone your *private* key?

Comment: this is not my private key, I replaced with dummy text (both keys actually) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer in chat:

as the `<recaptcha:...>` tags are parsed by some server side plugin, they were not rendered after writing them in client side JS. so replacing works fine, but plugin didn't...

Answer (score 0):

you can do any string operations (like search and replace) on `document.body.innerHtml`:

```
document.body.innerHtml = document.body.innerHtml.replace(/Loading\.\.\./g,
                                                          "<recaptcha...>");
```

Comment: i am trying this but no working: 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("123", "<recaptcha:recaptchacontrol ID='recaptcha' runat='server' PublicKey='kfldsjfh4378qyf43h4eidfhew' PrivateKey='sdflkdsfy908s6dfdsfkj' Theme='clean' />");

Comment: i think you'll need to use REGEX, so try `/123/g` instead of `"123"`

Comment: strange: I tried a simple example using a "html page" containing just "123", then running: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("123", "456");`, which produced "456".

Comment: no it is not working, the problem is in the html tags i think not the first part of the replace

Comment: yes i tried that too at first and it worked fine, the problem is with the html tags as i mentioned in my question :)

Comment: maybe because "<recaptcha:..." is a 3rd-party tag. try running your replacement, then call "alert(document.body.innerHtml)" or run firebug or whatever, to verify the tag is written. if it is, but no recaptcha is drawn, maybe you have to run some function to scan for the tag (which is usually done on page load by your recaptcha API).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8876/discussion-between-ali-issa-and-nonchip)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your "Loading..." text in a `<span>` with a unique id, such as

```
<span id="removeme">Loading...</span>
```

Then, if  you don't want to do much DOM-fu with that complex, namespaced tag, you can do the following:

```
var removeme = document.getElementById('removeme');
removeme.innerHTML = "<recaptcha:recaptchacontrol ...";
var recaptchaThing = removeme.firstChild;
removeme.removeChild(recaptchaThing);
var parent = removeme.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(recaptchaThing, removeme);
parent.removeChild(removeme);
```

This will replace the `<span>` with the `<recaptcha:recaptchacontrol>` element, after letting the browser figure out how to build the DOM for that bizarre element. If it turns out `<recaptcha:recaptchacontrol>` can't be placed inside of a `<span>` element, make it a `<div style="display:inline">` instead.

Comment: it cant be done from javascript since the <recaptcha:recaptchacontrol ... contains runat="server"

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that. I guess you have an ASP.NET backend and this control is a custom server tag (not a custom client tag like Facebook uses; I'm not as familiar with the ReCaptcha insertion process).